# ajax multiple request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

i am sending multiple ajax requests at a same time as ajax sends Asynchronous request but i want to execute second request until i get my first response. as first response may dependent on second one and so on .

here is my code

```
$.ajax({
        'url':'<?php echo $html->url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'priceofitem'));?>/'+menu_item_id,
        'type':'POST',
            success:function(result) {
                var price= valu*parseFloat(result);
                $('.total-price').html(price);
            }   
        });
```

Anybody have any idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ajaxQueue for this purpose

See the links

http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/

http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/10/11/ajaxqueue-and-jquery-1-3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to send syncronious request, and specify async :false

```
success:function(result) 
{                 
var price= valu*parseFloat(result);                 
$('.total-price').html(price);
},
async:   false
```

Comment: if we set async: false i cannot send another request until i get response of first

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you correctly, but this what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

set `async:false` e.g.

```
$.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo $html->url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'priceofitem'));?>/'+menu_item_id,
        type:'POST',
        async:false,
            success:function(result) {
                var price= valu*parseFloat(result);
                $('.total-price').html(price);
            }   
        });
```

Comment: if we set async: false i cannot send another request until i get response of first